# Using a variable number of object fields in a custom editor window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So far I have this working :

```
 EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical();
 for (int i = 0; i < numOfSprites; i++)
 {
   EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
   EditorGUILayout.TextArea("test "+i);
   EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(sprites[i], typeof(Sprite), true);
   EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
 }
 EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

I need to assign the selected sprite from the object field to it corresponding place in the sprites array. I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
sprites[i] = (Sprite)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(sprites[i], typeof(Sprite), true);
```

Comment: tried this before posting the question. Should have mentioned it. I'm using a property field now and it seems to be working I will answer my own q when I have time

Comment: @UriPopov yes you should. and this totally calls for another question